# Change server Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm working on an mvc .net application and I'm using Entity Framework. I have the same database in different servers and I want to change the current server. I tried to change the connection string in the web.config file but it didn't work. How to safely change the server?

Comment: Changing the connection string in the web.config should work.

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what did it do? Did it just not work or did it continue to connect to the previous DB?

Comment: I found where the problem is, in fact some tables had different names. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must replace Data Source

```
<connectionStrings>
<add 
name="AdventureWorksEntities"
connectionString="metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string='Data Source=.....;
Initial Catalog=....;
Integrated Security=True;
Connection Timeout=60;
multipleactiveresultsets=true'" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thank you Candie, it was just a problem with names of tables. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the connection string in web.config is all you need to do.

Make sure you are changing the right connection string (the one with the metadata). Entity Framework will automatically put a connection string in the web.config when the model is first created.

The correct connection string will look something like this:

```
<add name="AdventureWorksEntities"
connectionString="metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=localhost;
Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;
multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```